# 1 out of 7 test cases don't work with this simple C program to find sub-string

Tags: c, string, substring

I've been given an assignment to write a C program to find a sub-string with 7 test cases. I've written the program but it only passes 6 test cases. 7th one fails and I'm unable to identify the reason behind it.

Edit: Here's the question that I was given for the assignment.

> Write a program that takes two input strings S1 and S2 and finds if S2
>   is a substring of S1 or not. If S2 is a substring of S1, the program
>   should print the index at S1 at which there is a match. If S2 is not a
>   substring of S1, the program should print -1. If S2 appears in S1
>   multiple times, print the first index in S1 at which the match
>   occurred.

Here's the source code of the program that I've written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char st1[19];
    char st2[19];
    int cnt,i,k,c,len,m,sign;
    scanf("%s %s", st1, st2);
    len=strlen(st1);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        c=0;
        if (st1[i] == st2[c]) {
            m = i;
            sign = 0;
            cnt = 0;
            while(st2[c] != '\0' && sign!=1) {
                if (st1[m] == st2[c]) {
                    m++;
                    c++;
                    cnt++;
                } else
                    sign=1;
            }
            if (sign == 0) {
                printf("%d",i);
                k=1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (k != 1)
        if (sign!=0)
            printf("-1");
    return 0;
}
```

The 7th test case is as follows

**Input:**

> coolgoose oo

**Expected output:**

> 1

**Actual output:**

> 15

Edit 2: And here are the other test cases that were passed.

```
Input       Output

football foot   0

mickey mouse    -1

abcdefghijklmnopqrs s   18

helloworld helloworld   0

FrodoBaggins bagg   -1

Hell Hello  -1
```

Comment: It would help if you told people why 1 is the expected output for that test case and also show one of the test cases that works.

Comment: @user3386109 Because the control string "oo" is in the first position. ASRM: Would I be correct in assuming that the control string in the other six cases are single characters?

Comment: I've updated the question. It now includes the "question that I was given for the assignment".

Comment: @ASRM My question still stands: Are the other tests single characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually printing each match it finds: at character `1` and at character `5`. You should `break` out of the `for` loop when you find a match.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Eckert. Works perfectly. I'm such a dumbo. Thanks again.